# Where does android studio put .class file

Tags: android-studio

I make a new project and build it successfully.But I cannot find where android studio put .class files

I tried

1. search in build/generate
2. double shift
3. `find` command

But I cannot find `MainActivity.class` or some others.

Where does android studio put .class files?

Answer (score 4):

You can find them in the build/intermediates/classes/debug/* directory.

Comment: Newer version of Android studio has change the class directory.
Now in build/intermediates/javac/{your_flavor}/compile{your_flavor}JavaWithJavac/classes/*

Answer (score 1):

Rename the following .jar file to .zip and unzip it.

`build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar`